# Android 5 to 6 Issue: External Storage Path File.Exists() Broken / Looking for Alternative

Tags: java, android, file, path, permissions

Not sure if there are new constraints and this is no longer possible in Marshmallow.

I have been launching the associated app for a given file extension type with an `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.  The problem I have is that the following code returns false, where in Android 5 and earlier it returns true (simplified):

```
String _HOMEFOLDER = "/storage/sdcard0";
String fileName = _HOMEFOLDER + "/FolderCreatedByUser/filename.ext";
File file = new File(fileName);
if (file.exists()) { }
```

Our app is pre-loaded by our team on only specific model tablets, so the _HOMEFOLDER part of the path was modified as one of the input files in the app and read at launch per device or if data was loaded on an external SD card.

I have been looking at alternative solutions, such as using:

```
context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
//returns: /data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files
```

or

```
String strSDCardPath = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
if ((null == strSDCardPath) || (strSDCardPath.length() == 0)) {
    strSDCardPath = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_SDCARD_STORAGE");
}
//strSDCardPath: /storage/sdcard1
```

The second option would be great, except there is no path for internal SD storage and `EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET` doesn't come up on my Android 6 devices when executing on a cmd prompt:

```
adb shell
printenv
```

Is the first option my only choice, to move our file storage folder to be inside a special folder accessible only to our app such as:

`/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files`.

Does the Android SDK provide a method to create this folder and apply permissions?  What if I would like this folder to exist on the External SD card? What about separate users?

**Update: We have a lot of devices out in 'the wild' now which are going to break when users upgrade to Android 6 because the hard-coded path breaks in file.exists();  Is there a way to access /storage/... and the users home path with a hard-coded string, or is access to the users home folders now blocked? The app manifest includes permission to read/write to storage.**

**Our devices contain up to 100GB in this folder of documents which are single-time loaded to this folder before being given to customers. Moving the folder is a brutal option if we need to 'recall' ALL of the hundreds of tablets to manually update them.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDiretory() + "/FolderCreatedByUser/filename.ext";
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  So it looks like accessing works in some cases using the old accepted URI of /storage/sdcard0/ for example, but it does not work when passed as an action.intent to open the URI in an external app, eg an action to open a PDF in Adobe Reader.  Using this method does work!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is that the following code returns false, where in Android 5 and earlier it returns true

That code shouldn't work on Android 4.4+, except perhaps on devices that were upgraded from older versions of Android. You do not have access to arbitrary paths on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), short of rooting the tablet and mucking around with permissions. Devices that do not ship with the Play Store might allow access to arbitrary paths, though, as the no-removable-storage-access rule is enforced as part of compatibility testing by Google for Play ecosystem devices.

> Is the first option my only choice, to move our file storage folder to be inside a special folder accessible only to our app such as `/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files`

Your choices are [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and select locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> Does the Android SDK provide a method to create this folder and apply permissions?

Android will automatically create all necessary directories, at least once you stop hardcoding directory names and use methods to access them (e.g., `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDirs()`).

> What if I would like this folder to exist on the External SD card?

You are welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural). If that method returns 2+ entries, the second and subsequent ones are supposed to be on removable storage.

> What about separate users?

Each user has separate internal and external storage. Off the cuff, I forget the rules for multiple users and removable storage, though I presume each user has unique space on there too.

---

**UPDATE** based on updated question:

> Is there a way to access /storage/...

If you mean the stuff in your original code snippet, no.

> and the users home path

There is no "users home path" in Android.

> is access to the users home folders now blocked?

There is no "users home folders" in Android.

> The app manifest includes permission to read/write to storage.

There are permissions for [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). You are not using external storage, based upon your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will review the documentation on your website.  However, I need to try and solve accessing existing folders in the /storage/.. user home folder.  Is this blocked entirely now?

Comment: @thril: Quoting my answer: "That code shouldn't work on Android 4.4+, except perhaps on devices that were upgraded from older versions of Android. You do not have access to arbitrary paths on removable storage, short of rooting the tablet and mucking around with permissions." See also updated answer based on your updated question.

Comment: Rooting devices may be a quicker solution than manually moving files. This is not a large volume release through the Play store, they are essentially devices we manage.  Though, perhaps FileManager apps also do not have permission to access these folders anymore. I haven't tested yet.  The folders I am talking about are at the same level as eg Downloads and Pictures folders, thats what I mean by Home. Thanks.

Comment: @thril: "Though, perhaps FileManager apps also do not have permission to access these folders anymore" -- ones that shipped with the device may have access, given to them by device manufacturers. Other ones installed separately will not. "The folders I am talking about are at the same level as eg Downloads and Pictures folders, thats what I mean by Home" -- presumably, you are referring to the root directory of external storage.

Comment: Interestingly, some 3rd party apps can and some cannot. FileManager HD can, the FTP Server app cannot.  Our app can access the files when it uses them internally to the app via NanoHTTPD web-server, but when it tries to pass the URI to external apps, they cannot access it. For example, Adobe Reader says 'Error, the document path is not valid.'

Comment: @Deepak Goyal answer ended up working!  For the next release, we will start using the apps specified directory for better compatibility.  However, the downside is that if the app is uninstalled the 100+ GB in some cases will be wiped and need to be reloaded which can take 12 hours per device! Hopefully, upgrading the app does not wipe this folder!

Comment: @thril: "Goyal answer ended up working" -- that is external storage.

Comment: Yes. I guess internal storage is the OS accessible folders only, external storage is the internal SD chip, user accessible folders and secondary storage is an external SD card.  I noticed in your article you pointed out the poor choice of naming here... thanks for your help.